# Python mechanize - selecting a value and submiting doesn't work

Tags: javascript, python, mechanize, form-submit

The HTML code looks like this (its a field with a button next to it, where you can select a value):

```
<input type="text" name="account_name" class="sqsEnabled" tabindex="0" id="account_name" size="" value="" title='' autocomplete="off">
<input type="hidden" name="account_id" id="account_id" value="">

<button type="button" name="btn_account_name" id="btn_account_name" tabindex="0" title="Select Account" class="button firstChild" value="Select Account"
onclick='open_popup("Accounts", 600, 400,"",true, false,{"call_back_function":"set_return","form_name":"EditView","field_to_name_array":"id":"account_id","name":"account_name"}}, 
"single", true);' >
.....

#the submit button
<input title="Save" accesskey="a" class="button primary" onclick="var _form = document.getElementById('EditView'); _form.action.value='Save'; if(check_form('EditView'))SUGAR.ajaxUI.submitForm(_form);return false;" type="submit" name="button" value="Save" id="SAVE_HEADER">
```

When I select the value the HTML modify a previous line which look like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="account_id" id="account_id" value="30a4f430-5b15-8d7f-632a-52723fb0921a">
```

and in the input with name="account_name" has a string value "XXX LTD"

So I figure if will do this, I will submit the form successfully:

```
    br.select_form(nr=0)
    br.form.set_all_readonly(False)
    form = br.form
    form['account_name'] = "XXX LTD"
    form['account_id'] = "30a4f430-5b15-8d7f-632a-52723fb0921a"
    #other forms ...
    response = br.submit()
```

There is no error from Python, but the form isn't submitted. Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you create a dict `form` and doesn't use it, try:

```
form = br.form
form['account_name'] = "XXX LTD"
form['account_id'] = "30a4f430-5b15-8d7f-632a-52723fb0921a"
br.form = form # <--- here
response = br.submit()
```

Comment: Nope. Doesn't submit. I want to point out that if I comment this line: br.form.set_all_readonly(False), Python raise this error: ValueError: control 'account_id' is readonly

Answer (score 0):

Mechanize doesn't support JavaScript. Why do you have this tag?

You're not selecting form. Reaplce your for selection with:

```
br.select_form(nr=0)
```

Comment: I have other inputs which dont have JavasSript buttons like this one form['name'] = "Task name 1"

Comment: And how's that related to the question?

Comment: If I dont make this selection Python gives me this error: TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment